# How can I close an element when the div content or a button in the div is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div with some text that I want to appear on top of the parent div when a button is clicked. This means that with lots of text the open/close button (more info button) is blocked when this new div is active. So ideally I would like a button within the new div to be able to close it. I think I've written my JS wrong so that a close button won't work. I've tried adding in other rules, a whole new function to `display:none` on a button click and I'm stuck. Any help would be hugely appreciated. If possible I would like to stick to vanilla JavaScript too please.

```js
var infoBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("more-info");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < infoBtn.length; i++) {
  infoBtn[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight) {
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  })
}
```

```css
.work-projects {
  margin: 40px 0;
}

.work-boxes {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 90%;
  height: 40vh;
  min-height: 300px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.work-box-content {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: rgb(32, 32, 32);
  padding: 20px;
  width: 50%;
  border: 5px solid rgba(253, 225, 78);
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.work-projects h2 {
  color: turquoise;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.work-box-content .code-logo {
  flex-direction: row;
  align-self: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  max-width: 100%;
}

#PHP-pic {
  height: auto;
  margin: auto 0;
}

.project-links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.project-links img {
  height: 30px;
  width: auto;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.project-links a {
  padding: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.project-links a:hover img {
  filter: opacity(60%);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.sidenav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0 5px;
  z-index: 200;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: turquoise;
  text-align: center;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.25s ease-out;
}

.more-info {
  height: 30px;
  width: auto;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.sidenav p {
  font-size: 0.7em;
}
```

```html
<main class="main-page">
  <div class="work-projects" id="work-bookmark">
    <div class="work-boxes" id="sectionone">
      <div class="work-box-content">
        <h2>TITLE</h2>
        <div class="code-logo">
          <figure>
            <img id="HTML-pic" src="./images/HTML5.png" alt="HTML">
          </figure>
          <figure>
            <img id="CSS-pic" src="./images/CSS3.png" alt="CSS">
          </figure>
          <figure>
            <img id="JS-pic" src="./images/JS.png" alt="JS">
          </figure>
          <figure>
            <img id="PHP-pic" src="./images/php.png" alt="PHP">
          </figure>
        </div>
        <section class="project-links">
          <a class="github-project" href="https://github.com/adraf/Dan-Batchelor">
            <img src="./images/iconmonstr-github-2.png" alt="github logo">
          </a>
          <a class="linktoproject" href="http://danbatch.com/">
            <img src="./images/iconmonstr-share-11.png" alt="website link">
          </a>
        </section>
        <img class="more-info" src="./images/iconmonstr-info-1-240.png" alt="more information">
        <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
          <p>
            Text tetxt text Text tetxt textText tetxt textText tetxt textText tetxt textText tetxt textText tetxt textText tetxt textText tetxt textText tetxt textText tetxt textText tetxt textText tetxt textText tetxt textText tetxt textText tetxt textText tetxt
            text
            <br> Text tetxt text Text tetxt textText tetxt textText tetxt textText tetxt textText tetxt textText tetxt textText tetxt textText tetxt textText tetxt textText tetxt textText tetxt textText tetxt textText tetxt text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with a second event listener for the click on the div (which has the id `mySidenav`).

**Working example:**

```js
var infoBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("more-info");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < infoBtn.length; i++) {
  infoBtn[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight) {
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  })
  
  document.querySelector("#mySidenav").addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.style.maxHeight = null;
  });
}
```

```css
.work-projects {
  margin: 40px 0;
}

.work-boxes {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 90%;
  height: 40vh;
  min-height: 300px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.work-box-content {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: rgb(32, 32, 32);
  padding: 20px;
  width: 50%;
  border: 5px solid rgba(253, 225, 78);
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.work-projects h2 {
  color: turquoise;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.work-box-content .code-logo {
  flex-direction: row;
  align-self: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  max-width: 100%;
}

#PHP-pic {
  height: auto;
  margin: auto 0;
}

.project-links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.project-links img {
  height: 30px;
  width: auto;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.project-links a {
  padding: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.project-links a:hover img {
  filter: opacity(60%);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.sidenav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0 5px;
  z-index: 200;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: turquoise;
  text-align: center;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.25s ease-out;
}

.more-info {
  height: 30px;
  width: auto;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.sidenav p {
  font-size: 0.7em;
}
```

```html
<main class="main-page">
  <div class="work-projects" id="work-bookmark">
    <div class="work-boxes" id="sectionone">
      <div class="work-box-content">
        <h2>TITLE</h2>
        <div class="code-logo">
          <figure>
            <img id="HTML-pic" src="./images/HTML5.png" alt="HTML">
          </figure>
          <figure>
            <img id="CSS-pic" src="./images/CSS3.png" alt="CSS">
          </figure>
          <figure>
            <img id="JS-pic" src="./images/JS.png" alt="JS">
          </figure>
          <figure>
            <img id="PHP-pic" src="./images/php.png" alt="PHP">
          </figure>
        </div>
        <section class="project-links">
          <a class="github-project" href="https://github.com/adraf/Dan-Batchelor">
            <img src="./images/iconmonstr-github-2.png" alt="github logo">
          </a>
          <a class="linktoproject" href="http://danbatch.com/">
            <img src="./images/iconmonstr-share-11.png" alt="website link">
          </a>
        </section>
        <img class="more-info" src="./images/iconmonstr-info-1-240.png" alt="more information">
        <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
          <p>
            Text tetxt text Text tetxt textText tetxt textText tetxt textText tetxt textText tetxt textText tetxt textText tetxt textText tetxt textText tetxt textText tetxt textText tetxt textText tetxt textText tetxt textText tetxt textText tetxt textText tetxt
            text
            <br> Text tetxt text Text tetxt textText tetxt textText tetxt textText tetxt textText tetxt textText tetxt textText tetxt textText tetxt textText tetxt textText tetxt textText tetxt textText tetxt textText tetxt text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @biberman . I was so close with one of my attempts but wasn't using .querySelector. Really appreciate the help!

Comment: It would also work with ```document.getElementById("mySidenav")```...

Comment: I had 2 divs which I wanted to have the same functionality, so I added a `var bioText = document.getElementsByClassName("sidenav");
` to the class name instead and then `bioText[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.style.maxHeight = null; 
    });`. Thanks again for your help!